# How to use VBA to execute a macro based on an IF statement?

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I want to run an Excel VBA code (all it will do is delete specific cells within the same row and I've turned on relative reference so that I can apply the Excel VBA code to all rows, if there's the appropriate "X") based on whether there is an X in a certain cell.

Here's what I've tried so far (the Excel VBA code is just called "Biology"):

```
If Range("C22").Value = "X" Then
   Call macro_Biology
End If
```

I should add that I'm writing this under VBA section "GetATPLabel". Like I said, total noob, but I think I'm close, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to post all of your code, but it would be helpful to see the relevant portions. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if it is important that the *Biology* (or *macro_Biology*) macro needs to know which row it is supposed to work on. You can pass this information across to it with a parameter. Example:

```
Sub start_with_this()
    Dim rw As Long, lr As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        For rw = 2 To lr
            If UCase(.Cells(rw, "C").Value) = "X" Then
                Call macro_Biology(rw)
            End If
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub

Sub macro_Biology(r As Long)
    ' r is the row that was passed in.
    ' do something with r
End Sub
```

After initially starting the `start_with_this` macro, it goes through each cell in column C from row 2 to the last row with anything in it. If it finds an *X* or an *x* (case-sensitivity is removed by forcing the cell value to upper case before comparing) then it calls the second macro, `macro_Biology` and tells it what row to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that *Biology()* is a sub in a standard module:

```
Sub Biology()
    MsgBox "study biology!"
End Sub
```

To call this as you want, run:

```
Sub TestIt()
    If Range("C22").Value = "X" Then
        Call Biology
    End If
End Sub
```

To call *Biology()* automatically if the user types an **X** in cell **C22**, Insert the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set intrs = Intersect(Target, Range("C22"))
    If Not intrs Is Nothing Then
        If intrs.Value = "X" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Call Biology
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

To call *Biology()* automatically if a formula gives an **X** in cell **C22**, Insert the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Range("C22").Value = "X" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Call Biology
            Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```